# Trait runtime type of type parameter through TypeTag when used with Existential type in Scala

Tags: scala, runtime, traits, existential-type

I have `trait` with type parameter. To get the runtime type I use `TypeTag`. However, when this `trait` (and its classes) are used with `existential type` in a Collection, e.g. `List` or `Map`, `TypeTag` is "lost".

Here is an example of standard way to use Type Tag:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> trait Animal[T] {
     |   def typeT()(implicit t: TypeTag[T]) = t.tpe
     | }
defined trait Animal

scala> 

scala> class Dog extends Animal[Int] 
defined class Dog

scala> class Cat extends Animal[String] 
defined class Cat

scala> 

scala> val dog = new Dog 
dog: Dog = Dog@4aa88c93

scala> val cat = new Cat 
cat: Cat = Cat@2281e252

scala> dog.typeT
res46: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Int

scala> cat.typeT
res47: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String
```

As you can see, so far so good, the method `typeT` defined and implemented in the trait `Animal` works. However, when used with `List` and existential types, it failed working:

```
scala> val aa: List[Animal[_]] = List(dog, cat, dog)
aa: List[Animal[_]] = List(Dog@4aa88c93, Cat@2281e252, Dog@4aa88c93)

scala> aa(0).typeT
res52: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = _$1

scala> aa(1).typeT
res53: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = _$1
```

Explicit casting (like the following) for sure worked. But most of the time what is given is `List[Anima[_]]`. If another level of TypeCast is necessary, and how?

```
scala> aa(0)
res55: Animal[_] = Dog@4aa88c93

scala> aa(0).asInstanceOf[Dog]
res56: Dog = Dog@4aa88c93

scala> aa(0).asInstanceOf[Dog].typeT
res57: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Int
```

I understand that `aa(0)` is an `Animal[_]` which is the reason. But still, `aa(0)` is not only an `Animal[_]`, but a `Dog`. Why the `typeT` (or `TypeTag`) could not be used as if it were a normal method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `typeT()` is a method, so it will return a different value depending on your knowledge of the `Animal`. If the compiler can prove you have an `Animal[Int]`, then it can easily get a `TypeTag[Int]`. But with an existential type in `List[Animal[_]]`, you lose the type information contained in `Animal`. So when you select an arbitrary element from the list, all you know is that it's an `Animal[_]` when `typeT` is called, and nothing else. `typeT` does not know about the type parameter `T` for each instance. It has no way of proving it in this context.

The type cast of course works, because `asInstanceof[Animal[Cat]]` tells the compiler to forget what it knows. This if course can throw a `ClassCastException` when you get it wrong.

One way you can get it to work is by requiring the implicit `TypeTag[T]` on instantiation of an `Animal[T]`, and storing that value, rather than resolving it within a method. Unfortunately, this means you cannot use a trait.

```
abstract class Animal[T](implicit tt: TypeTag[T]) {
    val tpe = tt.tpe
}

class Dog extends Animal[Int]
class Cat extends Animal[String]
val dog = new Dog
val cat = new Cat

scala> val aa: List[Animal[_]] = List(cat, dog, cat)
aa: List[Animal[_]] = List(Cat@5a9faacf, Dog@675c379d, Cat@5a9faacf)

scala> aa(0).tpe
res6: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String

scala> aa(1).tpe
res7: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Int
```

Alternatively, you could express it using a little syntactic sugar on the implicit parameters:

```
abstract class Animal[T: TypeTag] {
    val tpe = implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe
}
```

Comment: I see. The type parameter is "lost" upon the method call in the existential case. I guess it also works for two type parameters (e.g. Animal[S, T]), but what is the correct "implicit" syntax for that?  `abstract class Animal[S,T](implicit ss: TypeTag[S], implicit tt: TypeTag[T]){...}` does not work.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's lost upon the method call, but the up-cast to `Animal[_]`. The method just doesn't have means to recover it. You need to remove the second `implicit` keyword. It is only needed once.

Comment: @Causality Would you say this answers your question?

Comment: you did answer my question. I have a quick follow up question that I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399090/how-to-cast-a-variable-to-certain-runtime-type-got-from-typecast-in-scala . Could you answer it as well?