# How to cast a variable to certain runtime type got from TypeCast in Scala

Tags: scala, types, casting

The `asInstanceOf[T]` works for "simple" case where the type `T` is given explicitly by code: e.g.

```
scala> val x: Any = 5
x: Any = 5

scala> x.asInstanceOf[Int]
res50: Int = 5

scala> val m1: Any = Map[String, Int]("a"->1, "b"->2)
m1: Any = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)

scala> m.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Int]]
res51: Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, 2 -> b)

scala> val m2: Any = Map[Any,Any]("a"->1, 2->"b")
m2: Any = Map(a -> 1, 2 -> b)

scala> m.asInstanceOf[Map[Any, Any]]
res52: Map[Any,Any] = Map(a -> 1, 2 -> b)
```

But when the type `T` is retrieved at runtime through `TypeTags`, `asInstanceOf[T]` does not work. For example:

```
scala> val intT = typeTag[Int].tpe
intT: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Int

scala> x.asInstanceOf[intT]
<console>:12: error: not found: type intT
              x.asInstanceOf[intT]
```

The error says it clear that `intT` is not a `type`. So `reflect.runtime.universe.Type` is not a real `type`? How to cast a value to certain type using `typeTag` information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`intT` isn't a type, but an instance of `Type`. Confusing, for sure. I'm not sure if there is something built into the reflection API that does this, but you can easily write a method that will cast to `A` given an element `Any` and a `TypeTag[A]`.

```
def cast[A](a: Any, tt: TypeTag[A]): A = a.asInstanceOf[A]

scala> val intT = typeTag[Int]
intT: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Int] = TypeTag[Int]

scala> val a: Any = 1
a: Any = 1

scala> cast(a, intT)
res101: Int = 1
```

Another variant using an implicit class:

```
implicit class TypeTagCast(a: Any) {
    def fromTypeTag[A](tt: TypeTag[A]): A = a.asInstanceOf[A]
 }

scala> a.fromTypeTag(intT)
res106: Int = 1
```

Comment: you have answered my question, but one question leads to another, which leads to another. Could you help address this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400439/cast-a-variable-to-runtime-type-from-existential-typed-typecast-in-scala

Comment: This can probably only be somewhat helpful, as it relies on knowing what `A` is for the `TypeTag`.