# Cast a variable to runtime type from existential typed TypeCast in Scala

Tags: scala, types, casting, existential-type

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380839/trait-runtime-type-of-type-parameter-through-typetag-when-used-with-existential) addressed how to use `TypeTag` to get runtime type of type parameters when used with `Existential` type. [Another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399090/how-to-cast-a-variable-to-certain-runtime-type-got-from-typecast-in-scala) addressed how to cast a variable to its runtime type retrieved from `TypeTag`.

My question builds on the aforementioned threads (kind of a combination of the two scenarios).  Parts of the code is duplicated from the two threads for clarity.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> def cast[A](a: Any, tt: TypeTag[A]): A = a.asInstanceOf[A]
cast: [A](a: Any, tt: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])A

scala> abstract class Animal[T](implicit tt: TypeTag[T]) {
     |   val ttag = tt
     | }
defined class Animal

scala> case object Dog extends Animal[Int]
defined object Dog

scala> case object Cat extends Animal[String]
defined object Cat

scala> val aa: List[(Animal[_], Any)] = List((Dog, 5), (Cat, "stringgg"), (Dog, 2))                                                                                                               
aa: List[(Animal[_], Any)] = List((Dog,5), (Cat,stringgg), (Dog,2))

scala> aa(0)._1.ttag
res25: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[_] = TypeTag[Int]

scala> aa(1)._1.ttag
res26: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[_] = TypeTag[String]

scala> cast(aa(0)._2, aa(0)._1.ttag)
res27: Any = 5

scala> cast(aa(1)._2, aa(1)._1.ttag)
res28: Any = stringgg
```

In short, the last two lines: `cast(value, TypeTag[_])` always return a value of type `Any`. But my intention is to cast these values to the correct type stored in `Dog|Cat.ttag`, which, unfortunately, is not `TypeTag[Int]` or `TypeTag[String]` but `TypeTag[_]` due to usage of `existential` type. Is there any solution for it?

Edit 1:

Despite the field `ttag` is of type `TypeTag[_]`, `ttag.tpe` does have the right "type" (but as an instance of `reflect.runtime.universe.Type`). Is it possible to use the `typetag.tpe` to cast to the right type?

Comment: It's been awhile since I've visited this post, but I've returned with some new thoughts. I don't think the `cast` method can work like you want it to, because the `TypeTag` is really only useful at runtime, and casting is done at compile time. The compiler needs to know what the return type of `cast` will be, but it can't infer the correct `A` from `TypeTag[_]`. Depending on what you want to do with the result, it might be possible to make it work in a different way.

Comment: Not only that `cast` is at compile time and `TypeTag` is at runtime, but that due to the `existential` type with collection,  `TypeTag` is on `Any` rather than its real type. The alternative approach I have been using is to use a super class to indicate the type, e.g.   `List((Dog, 5, IntType), (Cat, "stringgg", StrType), (Dog, 2, IntType))`, and then do a "runtime" cast through `asInstanceOf`. This "runtime" cast works for me in practice, but it is not safe and I wish there is a mechanism for compiler time cast.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the cast method as, 
`def cast[A](a: Any, tt: TypeTag[_]): A = a.asInstanceOf[A]` and

```
val x: Int = cast(aa(0)._2, aa(0)._1.ttag)
```

Comment: I don't think that answers the OP's question, though. Then you must manually tell the compiler what `A` is, which I they want to derive from the `TypeTag` alone.

Comment: @m-z the problem is, cast is inferred as Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

pair with path dependent type, you can type cast as following code shows:

```
import languageFeature.existentials

object TestExistential {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val aa: Array[(Animal[T], T) forSome {type T}] = Array((Dog, 5:Integer), (Cat, "stringgg"), (Dog, 2:Integer))
    aa.foreach(p=>{
      val ani = p._1
      val attr = p._2 // compiler weakness: existential type T is not unify with ani.castType
      assert(ani.attrTyp.isAssignableFrom(attr.getClass))// because of boxing, real type is Integer not Int
      assert(ani.clzTyp.isAssignableFrom(ani.getClass))
      val typedAni:ani.castType = ani.asInstanceOf[ani.castType]
      println(s"$typedAni of type Animal[${ani.attrTyp}] with $attr")
    })
  }

  abstract class Animal[T]{
    type castType = Animal[T]
    val attrTyp: Class[T]
    val clzTyp: Class[castType]
  }

  case object Dog extends Animal[Integer] {
    override val attrTyp: Class[Integer] = classOf[Integer]
    override val clzTyp: Class[Dog.castType] = classOf[Dog.castType]
  }

  case object Cat extends Animal[String] {
    override val attrTyp: Class[String] = classOf[String]
    override val clzTyp: Class[Cat.castType] = classOf[Cat.castType]
  }
}
```

if typing in scala repl, you can see the reply:

```sh
scala> val typedAni:ani.castType = ani.asInstanceOf[ani.castType]

typedAni: ani.castType = Dog

scala> typedAni

res0: ani.castType = Dog
```